# Editor UI widget not passing input to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am new to 'Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC' and am currently using the Editor UI widget to get data from a database and save changes to the database. The editor correctly displays the model data returned by the controller.

However, after making changes to the editor, the content in the editor is NOT being passed to the controller's HttpPost method and as a result the required validation message is displayed.

Any ideas as to why the Editor not passing the input to the underlying model??

Here is some code:

```
**@* Create Customer View *@**

@model KendoTest.Models.Customer
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
            @(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Notes).Name("NotesEditor").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:400px" }))
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Notes)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}



**// Customer Controller**

    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private KendoTestDbContext db = new KendoTestDbContext();

        //
        // GET: /Customer/Create

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Customer/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Customers.Add(customer);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(customer);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Share some code for the view, share some code for the controller, share what you see being post through a fiddler or firebug/devtools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution from Daniel of the Telerik team:

The value in the editor could not be passed to the post action if the property name does not match the Editor name. The Editor Name  is used for the textarea name and the ModelBinder will not be able to associate the value if the name is different. You could use the EditorFor helper and skip the Name method to generate the correct name:

```
@Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.PropertyName)
```

Comment: This response helped me.  Thank you!  I didn't realize that the object name should be the same for the Editor